# Updating a collection based on the value extracted from another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm revising my previous question. I have a collection named FileCollection with the following document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5e791a53185fbb070378660a"
},
"selectedfiles": [{
"inputfile": "https://localhost/_HAC-154_1584994899979.jpg",
"Selectedby: "Joe"
}]}
```

I need to read the value of selectedfiles.inputfile as a string variable. I'm trying to do this in Python using this code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
mydb = MongoClient(mongodbConnection)
myCollection=mydb.FileCollection
myValue=myCollection.selectedfile[0].inputfile.value
print(myValue)
client.close
```

the output is a JSON without having the actual value of inputfile. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us sample data, expected output and your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just because you're missing an `s`?

You had:

```
myValue=myCollection.selectedfile[0].inputfile.value
```

instead of:

```
myValue=myCollection.selectedfiles[0].inputfile.value
```